# Alternative to infopath

Tags: infopath

I'm looking for an application that provides similar functionality to what ms infopath provides.
It should preferably be free or open source. I have done some searching, however I cannot seem to find a suitable product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://freeform.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [BPC PowerForms](http://www.bpc-components.com/pages/sharepoint/power-forms) http://www.bpc-components.com/pages/sharepoint/power-forms

it's not free but recently they have launched the standard edition which is much cheaper.

Regards.